# Date() method of javascript while passing a timestamp adds a day to the result

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format

I am trying to get a date out of the time stamp I have (which is like the format : `2012-08-31T18:30:00`, coming from a date picker)

```
   var value = "2012-08-31T18:30:00";

   var date = new Date(value);
```

The result of this(date) is: `Sat Sep 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Here `Date()` function is adding a day to the given date. I have tried this for different inputs but always I get the result with one day added to it. I tried googling and searched Stack overflow too, but couldn't get a valid answer. Can anyone tell me why it is happening and how to resolve this?

Thanks,
Riswan

Comment: I read the comments you had posted and it looks like you want to take that string value and make it a Date() with the correct date and times set (regardless of the timezone). Have a look at my updated response and let me know if it helps. If not I'll definitely do anything I can to further understand the question and get you a solution.

Comment: Hi Chase, your solution is the one I expected. Thanks a ton..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your local timezone that's throwing off the value. You can find more out about UTC [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html).

> The value returned by [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) is a readable string in American English in the UTC time zone. The format of the return value may vary
>   according to the platform. The most common return value is a RFC-1123
>   formatted date stamp, which is a slightly updated version of RFC-822
>   date stamps.

```
var value = "2012-08-31T18:30:00";
var date = new Date(value);
date = date.toUTCString()
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LHvf4/)**

**EDIT**:

What I can gather from the comments you posted, you may be looking for something more like **[THIS EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LHvf4/2/)**:

```
var value = "2012-08-31T18:30:00"; //string value
var dateTime = value.split("T"); //split on T

var date = dateTime[0]; 
date = new Date(date); //set the date

var time = dateTime[1];
time = time.split(":"); //get the time into an array

//use set hours to set the time to 18:30:00:00 (hh:mm:ss:mm)
date.setHours(time[0], time[1], time[2], 0)

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

"2012-08-31T18:30:00" is referred to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) / UTC.

```
"2012-08-31T18:30:00" + India (UTC+5:30) = Sat Sep 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of the timestamp is in GMT, and `Date()` returns the local timestamp.

Use `date.toGMTString()` to keep it in GMT format.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue that I am facing is that I need a Date object as output. That's why I use Date() method. When I use toGMTString() I get a string as the output again. There is nothing much I can do about the input date format (It has to be in GMT). Any elegant way to resolve this?

Comment: @riswan - But when it's a date object, it's non-localized. It's converted to Indian Standard Time when you output it. So work with it in the any way you want as a Date, but when you output it you should use `toGMTString()`.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. This conversion is done in an application which uses a framework called SAP UI5. Here display and the output processing is taken care by the framework(which I wont be able to edit). The framework expects a Date object as an input, else it throws an exception at runtime. This is the reason why I am creating a Date object in the first place. This intermediate creation of the date object in Indian time while the expected time zone is in GMT is causing issues. I even tried Date( Date.UTC(value)) to create date object in UTC. But that is useless as well. Any help here?

Comment: @riswan - I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking, unfortunately... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @riswan do you need just the date, not the time? If so try `date.setMinutes(date.getTimezoneOffset());`

Answer (score 0):

`Sat Sep 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530`  is in GMT + **5h30**

And it's actually `2012-08-31T18:30:00` plus **5h30**